# mcrypt characters causing mysql errors

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, mcrypt

I'm having trouble getting php's mcrypt function to encrypt text in a way that can be stored in my mysql database.

Here's an example of a query that doesn't work:

```
UPDATE mydatabase.clients SET firstname='\'å»”é¶Q' WHERE id_client=65
```

But if I change it to be:

```
UPDATE mydatabase.clients SET firstname='Test' WHERE id_client=65
```

Then it works.  So it must be those crazy mcrypt characters throwing things off.

What do I do to my mysql database so it accepts those characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of a cipher is a string of bytes, not characters. You shouldn't store cipher text directly as text. Use a "binary" data type, or transform the byte string to text with something like Base-64.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column type to binary instead, this may work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are escaping the encrypted string. It's an important part to doing this right!

I've been working with MySQL and Mcrypt and I store my encrypted data and initialization vectors as binary and I escape all of these strings before they get put in a query. Works like a charm.